# Trying to convert <filesystem> output to a string

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I can load a vector with the file names in a directory using other methods, but I'm working on learning to use #include <filesystem>. Instead of printing to the console, I want to add it to a vector. It sounded easy, but I'm running into a problem where the vector apparently does not recognize the filesystem output as a string. I cannot figure out how to convert it to a string.

Since I could not directly push it to the vector, I tried sending it to a function but the error I get is "no suitable user-defined conversion from const std::filesystem::path to std::string exists."

I also tried changing const auto& files in every conceivable way to be a string without success. I just cannot get vecArray and files.path() to be the same file type.

Is it possible to get the following to work or do I need to change my whole approach?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(){
    std::string directoryPath{};
    std::vector < std::string > vecArray{};
    getline(std::cin, directoryPath);
    for (const auto& files : fs::directory_iterator(directoryPath)) {
      vecArray.push_back(files.path());
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string

Comment: This is a hint to read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) and look for a mechanism to convert to a `string`, something of which is literally the second "format observer".

Comment: Thank you paddy. I did previously read the ref you posted, but p.wstring() did not sink in. It's taking me time, but I'm gradually getting acclimated to the syntax of the C++ reference documents.

Comment: tadman, I am reading the doc for std::filesystem::path you provided. I did not know what "Format observers" are. Found a link that sheds more light about them. A bit confusing (for me), but I think I'm figuring it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the methods `c_str()` or `string()` [std::filesystem::path::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string)

```
vecArray.push_back(files.path().c_str());
```

Or

```
vecArray.push_back(files.path().string());
```

Comment: but what if it's not  ascii

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to use
`std::vector <std::filesystem::path> ..`
or use `std::wstring`. latter isn't that light to code as it looks